# UDP Broadcast received data looks like 2 dicts but are somehow combined as one?

Tags: python, python-2.6

The code below sends an UDP broadcast to get data from two OW-server's on the LAN. The response comes back as a :

{u'Product': u'OWServer_v2-Enet', u'Name': u'OWServer_v2-Enet_19', u'IP': u'10.0.1.19', u'TCPIntfPort': u'0', u'HTTPPort': u'80', u'MAC': u'00-04-A3-B1-F1-86', u'Bootloader': u'POST', u'FWVer': u'1.44', u'NETBios': u'EDSOWSERVER19   '}
{u'Product': u'OWServer_v2-Enet', u'Name': u'OWServer_v2-Enet_20', u'IP': u'10.0.1.20', u'TCPIntfPort': u'0', u'HTTPPort': u'80', u'MAC': u'00-04-A3-C1-43-86', u'Bootloader': u'POST', u'FWVer': u'1.44', u'NETBios': u'EDSOWSERVER20   '}

Anything I do sees the two dicts as one for example print resp["Name"] returns

OWServer_v2-Enet_19

OWServer_v2-Enet_20

There is no space or comma between the two dict so I cannot split them.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

```
import socket
import json 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,     socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, True)
s.sendto("D", ('<broadcast>', 30303))

while True:
    resp = s.recv(1024)

    resp = json.loads(resp)

    print resp
```

Comment: Hint: Add some debugging print statements between each line of code.  You will quickly see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried printing the results of each resp. The first one shows two strings in curly brackets {string}{string} and the second one is the json conversion which shows two dicts in curly brackets {dict}{dict}. My problem is I cannot figure out how to separate the separate the two. Some example code would sure be appreciated :)

Comment: If the response were really two dicts, it would not be valid JSON and the parsing would fail.  It sounds like what is happening is you are iterating over the loop body twice.  If you add some debugging statements at the start and end of the loop body you should clearly see this.